# Access In memory Database with 2 difference DbContext in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I have 2 different DbContext in EntityFramework core 6. But they refer to same In Memory database:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FirstDbContext>(op => { op.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"); });
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SecondDbContext>(op => { op.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"); });
```

I want use one of the context for writing in Database and another for reading. (CQRS)
For writing in database I use Set for inserting and it writes in database successfully.
but when I want to retrieve from second dbcontext it doesn't return any data (Empty Master).

```
    private readonly FirstDbContext firstDb;
    private readonly SecondDbContext secondDb;

    public TestController(FirstDbContext firstDb, SecondDbContext secondDb)
    {
        this.firstDb = firstDb;
        this.secondDb = secondDb;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public void Set()
    {
        var master = new First.Master
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Master"
        };
        var detail = new First.Detail
        {
            DetailName = "DetailName",
            MasterId = 1
        };
        var detail2 = new First.Detail
        {
            DetailName = "Detail2Name",
            MasterId = 1
        };
        firstDb.Masters.Add(master);
        firstDb.Details.Add(detail);
        firstDb.Details.Add(detail2);
        firstDb.SaveChanges();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Get()
    {
        var masters = secondDb.Masters.Include(x => x.Details).ToList(); //Empty means count equals 0
    }
```

Just I want to know why it doesn't read data from database while their name are same?

Comment: Is this called as a part of a test? If so then show how you've setup your test. It not, have you seen this notice in the documentation? `The In-Memory provider was not designed for use outside of testing environments and should never be used as such.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/

Comment: It is a sample application for CQRS with in memory database. Just I want to see can I access data with another dbcontext? @Karl-JohanSjögren

Comment: Test on real database provider. In-Memory is fake provider for tests.